# Laravel one to many get data

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm very bad with these relationships in Laravel and I cant get my one to many relationship to work. Lets say I have a friend system like this:

Table Users:

```
id | username | password
```

Table Friends:

```
id | person1(int) | person2(int)
```

**person1 and person 2 are the ID's of a user in the table Users**

Now I have these 2 models:

```
class Friend extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'friends';

    public function friend_relations(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

and:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

Now what I am doing is, after logging in, I want to show friends on the home page with the ID of the person logging in. So to get this I'd have it run like this:

```
$friends = Friend::where('person1', $id)->get();
```

Now this will give me the ID's of both of the persons, now I want to get the username that belongs to that user without running unnecessary extra queries so I would use a one to many relationship. However I cant seem to get the query to instantly get the name of the friends of the user logged in.

I tried something like:

```
$friends = Friend::where('person1', $id)->friend_relations;
```

and:

```
$friends = Friend::all()->friend_relations()->where('person1',$id)->get();
```

gives me: `Call to undefined method friend_relations()`

but this will give me the error: `Undefined property friend_relations`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationships are a little off because you may be thinking about this one a little wrong.

Even though it may not look like it, this is a belongs to many relationship and your `friends` table is actually a pivot table relating your `users` table to itself.

To further simplify this, you should rename the columns in your `friends` table so it's more clear what is what.  `person1` and `person2` are incredibly vague and will only serve to confuse.  With that said, I'm going to assume the two columns are `user_id` and `friend_id`.  If you wish to not do this, just assume when I say `user_id`, I mean `person1` and `friend_id` would map to your `person2`.

With all that said, this becomes a fairly simple problem.  Add the following to your `User` model.

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

Now in order to retrieve a user with their friends, you can do the following.

```
$user = User::with('friends')->find($id);
$friends = $user->friends; // This will return a collectino of friends.
```

Additionally, your `Friend` model becomes unnecessary so you can feel free to delete that.

### Edit:

Now `$friends` is going to be a `Collection` (you can think of this as a sort of array) of `User` objects.  There are going to be 0, 1 or many `User` objects inside the Collection so it doesn't make any sense to try to use `$friends->date` because it doesn't know which `User`'s date within that collection to grab from.

You will need to loop through it to access each User's properties.

```
foreach($friends as $friend) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $friend->name;
    echo 'Date: ' . $friend->date;
}
```

Comment: This worked. Just a question before I accept it. What is the purpose of: `User::class` part? I know you put the name of your class there but I've never seen ::class behind it. (FYI I'm using Laravel 4.2)

Comment: Since it's 4.2, feel free to put the class name in quotes.  Because 5.0 and newer introduced namespaces, it's a way to easily get the fully qualified class name that was introduced in PHP 5.5.  If you do it that way, make sure whatever servers you are using have at least PHP 5.5, otherwise you should just use the quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I used it in quotes and it still works. 1 quick extra question: What if I have another belongs to many relation like friends. Can I just edit the eloquent from this: `$user = User::with('friends')->find($id);` or do I have to make a new one? If I can just edit the other one to get everything from 1 query how would I do that?

Comment: Yeah, you can pass in an array of relations like `$user = User::with(['friends',  'otherRelation'])->find($id);`

Comment: Sorry to bother you once again but I tried it with another belongs to many relation and I'm getting no results apparently. `$user = User::with(['friends', 'messages'])->with('messages')->find($id);`and then:
`$messages = $user->messages;`. Kind of hard to show everything in comments. Can you help in chat?

Comment: You don't need the second `with('messages')`.  This might need to be its own question and to be able to see the table structure

Comment: Wait I fixed it. I did something that apparently cant happen thats why it didnt work. Is there a way to get the current query to show all the information in the friends database? I tried for example: `$friends->date;`, but this doesnt show up.

Comment: I've modified the answer to hopefully help